# ASUS Maximus Hero VII troubles

Tags: linux, audio, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

A lot of problems with motherboard ASUS Maximus Hero VII (Core i7-4770K, Geforce GTX 760, two SSD) and 2 OS installed separately on SSD - Win8.1 and Linux Mate 17.

1. I can't use two monitors together (VGA from processor and HDMI from graphic card) - I set properties in BIOS (last version) for two monitors and after POST get FF error and reboot.
2. After using linux in Windows changing a system time, why?
3. In Linux I have a sound but with noises, reinstalling audio driver and nothing changed.
4. PC turn on when I'm using sleep mode without any touch.
5. And the biggest trouble: if I changing setting in BIOS or using Linux I can't load a system because BIOS freezes and I get b2 and AE errors on LED.

Thank you for any help)

Comment: You have update the firmware correct?

Comment: #2 is probably due to different settings in Windows and Linux as to writing the time back to the BIOS and whether it's localized or GMT . . . for #5 start with the default and modify settings one at a time, trying to figure out which setting is causing the issue . . .

Comment: Firmware updated correctly.

Comment: After updating a last BIOS version #1,3 solved.